# Access a client's website via VPS IP address (Froxlor Server Management Panel)

Tags: web-hosting, ip-address, vps, ubuntu

Many control panels (cPanel, vestaCP, etc) allow users to access their site using the server's ip address like this:

```
123.456.789.011/~some-domain.com
```

Where `123.456.789.011` is the ip address of the vps/dedi server hosting the site.

In *Froxlor Server Management Panel* however, I can't seem to figure out how to let clients access their websites who's domain names haven't been set up yet.

Is there a way I can provide clients with a temporary URL to access their site while their domain name is being set up?

Comment: you can ask them to add an entry of the temporary domain name in their local machine's `hosts` file. e.g.
`123.456.789.011 some-domain.com`

Comment: @Nikhil Other control panels usually provide that by default. I think froxlor does too but I just can't figure out how it works